# Xcode pushes the .xcodeproj file

Tags: c++, xcode, git, github, version-control

I created a Xcode project and pushed it into my GitHub repo(new). However, it sends not only my code files, but also the .xcodeproj file. How to push only the folders and files I need?

I tried to create the .gitignore file manually, and then push the project using Xcode, but it still pushed the .xcodeproj file.

Comment: The `git push` command sends (pushes) *commits*. That's not "files", not "folders", but *commits*. Each commit *contains* a full snapshot of *every* file (that it contains), as a sort of permanent archive, so if you have a commit that contains a `.xcodeproj` file, and you have `git push` send that commit, it will send *all* the files, including that one. If you don't want that file in the commit, make sure you don't *commit* that file.

Comment: Note that a commit, once made, is (mostly) permanent and (completely) read-only, so you can't *remove* the file from *existing commits*. You can make *new* commits that lack the file, and that's what you should do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to record the deletion of that file locally, and push said deletion:

```
git rm --cached --  .xcodeproj 
git commit -m "delete .xcodeproj"
git push
```

Then:

- that file would be ignored: check that with `git check-ignore -v --  .xcodeproj`
- that file would no longer be pushed, or visible on the remote side